# update privilege for user accessing through dblink

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

We have a current setup where from oracle 10 we access oracle 7 and update its records. However, since 10 can't access 7 through db link. We had to use oracle 9 to act as bridge between 10 and 7. Picture it as below

ORACLE 10g dblink to  Oracle 9i dblink to Oracle 7

My issue is the user (10g) we are using is getting insufficient privilege error when try to update the records in oracle 7.

I have tried update the records from oracle 9 to 7 and there was no error. So I assume a privilege issue between 10 and 9. How do I check if my user in 10g can update records in oracle 7 via oracle 9?

Comment: wow, oracle 7 was released in June 1992, so, over 23 years ago, and support ended in 2003, 12 years ago. :) http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Oracle_7

Comment: and 10g support ended > 3 years ago: http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Oracle_10g You need a 12c in the tier. Just kidding :)

Comment: Can you update 9i from 10g?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that this is not possible.

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/ds_txns003.htm

The distributed transactions requires a **global coordinator** and a negotiation between it as a master and the others. Your architecture will require that 9i node is in the same time a coordinator and a coordinated node. This is just a bet. Reading carefully the doc may explain better why it cannot be possible. Making it to work will demonstrate the oposite, but I'm pessimistic about this chance.

My opinion is that you should try to do it asynchronously, not in a transaction(which will involve more work for sure...)